# Generic way to install any installer unattended

Tags: inno-setup

I am writing an Inno setup kit where I need to install various updates like Service Pack 3 for XP, DotNet Framework 4 and etc.

My problem is I want to make a generic kit which will take any exe and run it in silent mode i.e. unattended installation. I am aware of different flags that will do these for e.g. for SP3 `/quiet` and for DotNet framework `/q`. I would like to know how can I make my inno setup kit a generic one so that whatever exe I pass, it should install it in silent mode.

Comment: That's nearly impossible. You would have to detect if the binary file is an installer (there is no common way), and if so, what kind it is (if it's e.g. NSIS, Inno Setup, MSI, which I guess could be done by reading some common signature, but it would not be much reliable), because only then you would know which parameters that installer understands.